# hyperlinks in markers in My Maps google maps not working/clickable in ios/android apps

Tags: ios, google-maps-markers, url-scheme

I have a map built in My Maps(Not API) I am using iframe to embed it on my website. The markers on it has an external bit.ly url/hyperlink in the info. Whenever my responsive website is accessed through a mobile browser, it opens native google maps app in iOS and gives option to either open in google maps app or chrome browser in android.
When the map is loaded in a mobile browser the bit.ly links show and work fine as they are clickable.
But whenever opened in google maps app, it shows as just text not as hyperlinks hence they are not clickable.

I have tried importing data to my maps markers from a spreadsheet that has those links marked as hyperlinks, but it's not solving the problem.

I cannot use Maps API.
I do not have access to add any html/javascripts on the website.
All I can do is add a button on my site which opens the url of my map stored on "Google My Maps"

Comment: **Google My Maps** you meant is about this [link](https://www.google.com/mymaps)? It is required the authentication if you talk about this one.

Comment: yes. My map is set as public so anyone with the link can view it.

Comment: @GJ04001Bhavnagar did you found any solution ?? to create link in Google Map

Comment: @Osify have you found any solution ?

Comment: @Chaudhary, it was long time ago, I forgot the solution already :) but as I could understand now embed google map to any of the app, need to have their api token, display map is free, I think, navigation of direction should be charge when reach the limit